# How can I apply an effect to the hovered element only?

Tags: jquery, css

When i do mouse over on single list item then the effect is showing for all the rest of list items. I want to show the effect on single list item.

Here is the code :

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.thumbs li a').hover( function(){
            $('.thumbs li a').find('div').css({'opacity':'1'});
            },
            function(){
            $('.thumbs li a').find('div').css({'opacity':'0'});
            });
    });    
</script>

 <div id="thumbs-wrapper">
 <ul class="thumbs">
 <li> <a href="#"><img src="images/Adrian_Shaughnessy-325x325.png" />
  <div><h2> This is image 1</h2> </div></a> 
  </li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/allan_yu-325x325.jpg" />
<div><h2> This is image 2</h2> </div></a>
  </li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/armin_vit_secrethandshake-325x325.jpg" />
<div><h2> This is image 3</h2> </div></a>
  </li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/bburwell_Tsh-325x325.jpg" />
<div><h2> This is image 4</h2> </div></a>
  </li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/beverly_fresh_2-325x325.jpg" />
<div><h2> This is image 5</h2> </div></a>
  </li>

      </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$('.thumbs li a')` to find `div` within the source `element` that *triggred* the event instead of all elements returned by selector `$('.thumbs li a')`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.thumbs li a').hover( function(){
            $(this).find('div').css({'opacity':'1'});
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('div').css({'opacity':'0'});
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumbs li a').hover( function(){
        $(this).closest('div').css({'opacity':'1'});
        },
        function(){
        $(this).closest('div').css({'opacity':'0'});
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumbs li a').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('div').css({
            'opacity': '1'
        });
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('div').css({
            'opacity': '0'
        });
    });
});
```

- `$('.thumbs li a').find('div')` gets all the divs inside all the anchors.
- `$(this).find('div')` will get only the specific div inside the anchor being hovered on currently.

Answer (score 0):

U can try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.thumbs li a').hover( function(){
            $(this).find('div').css({'opacity':'1'});
            },
            function(){
            $(this).find('div').css({'opacity':'0'});
            });
});
```